# d3.js pan and zoom with ForeignObject

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to apply zoom and pan on an SVG that contains ForeignObject.

But when I zoom or pan they changes don't apply for the HTML parts.
When i move the elements around the DIVs just stay ion their original position,
Just like transitions are ignored by foreign objects.

This is what I do:

```
    var title = viewport.append("g").selectAll(".node-title")
    .data(dataset.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("foreignObject")
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .html(function(d){return '<div title="'+d.title+'"><div class="node-title">' + d.title + '</div></div>'})
    .attr("class", "node-title")
    .style("top", function(d){return d.y + 2 +'px'})
    .style("left",function(d){return d.x + 6 +'px'});
```

Is the problem with the positioning?
Any way to force changes on these parts as well?

Comment: Can you show us your code? It looks like you're positioning the HTML elements absolutely and not relatively to the SVG elements, but it's impossible to tell what's going on without more information.

Comment: Added the code for the foreignObjects, thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the position for the `div`? Also, you don't need a `body`, just the `div` should be enough.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I did, what I did was to resize and reposition the foreign objects inside the zoom function by changing their attributes seperatly according to the d3.event properties. I'll add the code I used if it helps.

Comment: Yes please share the code (if you've still have it), it would help me+others a lot. Having the same issue at the moment. zoom and moving  works but not the dynamic positioning of the div. Goal is that it should rotate with the earth-globe